Page Breaks In Nested Free Marker Tables
I am using Free Marker for an Netsuite custom form. I am attempting to iterate through each item in the record object and create a row for the respective entry.
I have separated the entries out by Billing Class, the works just fine. But the page break logic is not working as excepted. The page is NOT breaking from the <pbr></pbr> tag.
Here is the code for this section
<table style="width: 100%; border: 0px;">
<tr>
<td align="center">
    <p><strong style="font-size: 10;">foo bar, LLC</strong></p>
    <p><strong style="font-size: 12;">Time by Job Detail</strong></p>
    <p><strong style="font-size: 12;">${record.job}</strong></p>
    <hr class="thick-hr" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="underline-container"><span class="underline">Date</span></td>
            <td class="underline-container"><span class="underline">Name</span></td>
            <td class="underline-container"><span class="underline">Billing Status</span></td>
            <td class="underline-container"><span class="underline">Duration</span></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Grouping by Billing Class -->
        <#assign billingClasses = [] />
        <!-- Get distinct billing classes -->
        <#list record.item as timeEntry>
            <#if !billingClasses?seq_contains(timeEntry.item)>
                <#assign billingClasses += [timeEntry.item] />
            </#if>
        </#list>
        <#assign rowsPerPage = 30 />
        <#assign rowCount = 0 />
        <#assign totalDuration = 0 />

        <!-- Iterate through each billing class -->
        <#list billingClasses as billingClass>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">${billingClass}</td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Iterate through items that belong to the current billing class -->
            <#list record.item?filter(it -> it.item == billingClass) as timeEntry>
                <#if rowCount != rowsPerPage>
                    <tr>
                        <td>${timeEntry.billeddate}</td>
                        <td>${timeEntry.employeefullname}</td>
                        <td>${timeEntry.item}</td>
                        <td>${timeEntry.quantity}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <#assign totalDuration += timeEntry.quantity />
                    <#assign rowCount = rowCount + 1 />
                <#else>
                    <!-- Page Break when reaching the rowsPerPage limit -->
                    </table><pbr></pbr><table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">${billingClass}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>${timeEntry.billeddate}</td>
                        <td>${timeEntry.employeefullname}</td>
                        <td>${timeEntry.item}</td>
                        <td>${timeEntry.quantity}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <#assign totalDuration += timeEntry.quantity />
                    <#assign rowCount = 1 /> <!-- Reset rowCount after page break -->
                </#if>
            </#list>
        </#list>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">Total:</td>
            <td style="font-weight: bold;">${totalDuration}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

Any guidance is appreciated!
I am trying to create a page break after a certain number of rows is reached in Free Marker.

I ended up breaking the tables out so they were no longer nested. This seemed to have fixed the issue.
    <!-- First Table: Header Information -->
    <table style="width: 100%; border: 0px;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <p><strong style="font-size: 10;">foo bar, LLC</strong></p>
                <p><strong style="font-size: 12;">Time by Job Detail</strong></p>
                <p><strong style="font-size: 12;">${record.job}</strong></p>
                <hr class="thick-hr" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <!-- Second Table: Data Rows -->
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="underline-container"><span class="underline">Date</span></td>
            <td class="underline-container"><span class="underline">Name</span></td>
            <td class="underline-container"><span class="underline">Billing Status</span></td>
            <td class="underline-container"><span class="underline">Duration</span></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Grouping by Billing Class -->
        <#assign billingClasses = [] />
        <!-- Get distinct billing classes -->
        <#list record.item as timeEntry>
            <#if !billingClasses?seq_contains(timeEntry.item)>
                <#assign billingClasses += [timeEntry.item] />
            </#if>
        </#list>
        <#assign totalDuration = 0 />

        <!-- Iterate through each billing class -->
        <#list billingClasses as billingClass>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">${billingClass}</td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Iterate through items that belong to the current billing class -->
            <#list record.item?filter(it -> it.item == billingClass) as timeEntry>
                <tr>
                    <td>${timeEntry.billeddate}</td>
                    <td>${timeEntry.employeefullname}</td>
                    <td>${timeEntry.item}</td>
                    <td>${timeEntry.quantity}</td>
                </tr>
                <#assign totalDuration += timeEntry.quantity />
            </#list>
        </#list>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">Total:</td>
            <td style="font-weight: bold;">${totalDuration}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


If you are printing a PDF NetSuite's BFO engine actually handles page breaks in tables for you. If you want your table's headers to repeat when you page break you can create a <thead> element on your table see https://bfo.com/products/report/docs/tags/tags/tbody.html
If you have a nested table and want to avoid a page break you can add page-break-inside="avoid" to your nested table element. There are also page-break-after1 and page-break-before attributes for finer control.
https://bfo.com/products/report/docs/tags/atts/page-break-inside.html
https://bfo.com/products/report/docs/tags/atts/page-break-after.html

Thank you for your response. I am still having issues with page breaks, even after removing the logic for page break after a certain number of rows has been added.

I broke the tables out so they were not nested. That seemed to fix my issue. Thank you again!
